# How accept cookies in cypress.io

Tags: cookies, automated-tests, cypress

Hello Now I learn testing with cypress.io but I dont know how accept cookies with cypres.

```
cy.get('button accept class').click()
```

This code dont work I want accept cokies on

```
https://www.kiwi.com/en/
```

Answer (score 2):

One 'brutal' way to do it :

```
describe('Test Suite MakeMyTrip', function(){

it('Test Demo', function(){

    cy.visit('https://www.kiwi.com/en/')

    cy.get('section.ModalSection__StyledModalSection-sc-1ayrdn8-0 button').contains('Accept').click({force: true})

})})
```

I suggest you start learning css selectors : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
or you won't be able to select the element you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you than I find little mistake in my code.

```
cy.get('[data-test=acceptCookies]:visible').click()
```

Thank you here is my code

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just go by storing the cookie you check to show you cookie banner.

```
describe("Test", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.setCookie(
      "cookies_consent",
      JSON.stringify({ cookies_analytics: "granted", cookies_marketing: "granted" })
    );
  });
```